# How to define property types when passing props to grandchildren in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component `foo` inside my HTML and I pass a parameter to it like this:

`<foo some="Some String"></foo>`

Now inside the `foo` component I define the property type and default value like so:

```
 export default {
    name: "foo",
    props: {
        some: {
            type: String,
            default() { return '' }
        }
    }
}
```

The `foo` component's template has another component `bar` which I pass the `some` property: `<bar :some="some"></bar>`.

Now my question is: do I need to again define the type and default value for the `some` property, this time inside the `bar` component? So basically copy the props code from the `foo` component and paste it into the `bar` component or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` has ensured the type and default value, so there is no need to validate them in `bar`. If the type were something that has special behavior (e.g., boolean), you would need to specify it, but there's nothing special about string.

Answer (score 0):

> Every component instance has its own isolated scope. This means you cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data in a child component’s template. Data can be passed down to child components using props.

[Passing data with props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props)

---

What you need here is to use [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots):

Scoped slots allows you to pass props down from Parent components to Child components without coupling them together.

Comment: I am not directly referencing parent data.

Comment: Yeah; I just referenced with a link to inform you that's not possible.

Comment: Also updated my answer. Look on that which will help you.